# Purpose of 2530 Hz resonator?

Tags: resonance

I stumbled upon [this](https://aukro.cz/keramicky-rezonator-tesla-2530-hz-6917419201) advertisement. I would like to know what is the purpose of this 2530 Hz 3-pin ceramic resonator?

[image]

Comment: And I'd like to know why you need to know this. You can ask the manufacturer who buys these but you'll probably not get an answer as that's usually considered confidential information.

Comment: XO means crystal (Xtal) oscillator . It has 3 pins. But no idea on useful purpose.

Comment: The purpose? To resonate at 2530 Hz.

Comment: @Felthry I get resonances of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ov5FJhqEKYg

Comment: I found a picture of a number of SK85422/SK85432 parts; they have a variety of marks other than XO: V0, V2, V5, W3, X2, so I think the X0 is a lot number as Spehro Pefhany suggests, rather than an abbreviation for xtal oscillator. http://www.drbal.cz/material/fotky/8909.jpg

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a  crystal filter or resonator.

My guess is that it was used in Soviet-era telecom systems (perhaps in the CO of PSTN networks or military communications) either to generate tones (eg. DTMF or something similar) or to filter them (to decode the tones). The frequency of the resonators is well within the audio range so it could be transmitted over analog (POTS) telephone lines. This is partially confirmed by the presence of matched frequency oscillator and filter types as indicated below. I don't know which of the two types is offered in the advertisement.

From [this](https://list.hw.cz/pipermail/hw-list/2004-March/170463.html) source, here are the [TESLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_(Czechoslovak_company)) part numbers and frequencies of its siblings:

> 1850 Hz SK85422
>
> 1850 Hz SK85432
>
> 1950 Hz SK85422
>
> 1950 Hz SK85432
>
> 2160 Hz SK85422
>
> 2160 Hz SK85432
>
> 2280 Hz SK85422
>
> 2400 Hz SK85422
>
> 2530 Hz SK85422
>
> 2670 Hz SK85422

The posting says something about radio station selection but that's clearly incorrect. The XO is just a lot number or something and means nothing of value.

Comment: They're almost, but not quite, spaced nicely for musical oscillators -- the frequency ratios are 1.054:1 (apart from a missing step at ~2055 Hz), while 12-tone equal temperament should be spaced at 1.059:1. The difference stacks up, though; 2670 / 1850 = 1.443, instead of the expected perfect fifth (1.498:1 in 12-TET or 1.5:1 in Pythagorean tuning).

Comment: "station selection" could be a selective calling system, ie, use a pilot tone to open the squelch of a desired subset of receivers, lessening the annoyance of unrelated traffic to those who need to monitor a shared channel.  This has also been done with ongoing continuous sub-audible tones, and more similarly, with prefixing DTMF ones.